# Visual Studio Deploy to device Stucked Universal App

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, device, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm trying to deploy a universal app to a windows phone (development ready Lumia 520) device (I could deploy with Visual Studio 2015 RC).

Now that I'm using the latest visual studio and windows 10 sdk tools if I try to deploy to device (I'm using ARM) then the output just says:

Deploying started...

And gets stuck forever (I can still use visual studio) but it never ends.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change my phone device to developer mode.